# Why does the code coverage report say my library isn't being covered?

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage

I am attempting to generate code coverage for a small test library. The library only consists of two files.

calculator.cpp:

```
#include "calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator()
{

}

Calculator::~Calculator()
{

}

void Calculator::addNumbers(int x, int y)
{
  this->result = x + y;
}
```

calculator.h:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H
class Calculator
{
public:
  Calculator();
  ~Calculator();
  void addNumbers(int x, int y);
};

#endif
```

I have a unit test for this library that is being executed. It includes the library and runs fine. I have set the cmake_cxx_flags to include -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage in the top level CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 --coverage")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 --coverage -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs")

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

I am using a script to take the gcno and gcda files that are generated on build to generate a human readable report.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_DIR="$1/bin/ExecutableTests/Coverage"
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

component=Calculator
dependency=calculator
script=test_calculator.sh
unit_test=unit_test_calculator

mkdir $OUTPUT_DIR/$component

cd "$1"/bin/

make clean || exit 1
make || exit 1
# Create baseline coverage
lcov -c -i -d "$1"/bin/src/"$component"/CMakeFiles/"$dependency".dir -o "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.base
# Run the test
$1/scripts/$script $1
# Create test coverage
lcov -c -d "$1"/bin/test/$component/CMakeFiles/"$unit_test".dir -o "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.run

lcov -d "$1/test/$component" -a "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.base -a "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.run -o "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.total

genhtml --branch-coverage -o "$OUTPUT_DIR/$component" "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.total
rm -f "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.base "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.run "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.total
```

I can see that the data files are being generated for the library; however when I view the report that is generated from the script it shows that the library is never touched. This is clearly wrong as illustrated by my unit test.

```
#include "lest_basic.hpp"
#include "calculator.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int addResult(int x, int y)
{
  Calculator calc1;
  return calc1.addNumbers(x, y);
}

const lest::test specification[] =
{

  CASE( "Addition" )
  {
    std::cout << "Starting Addition testing..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Adding 1 and 2..." << std::endl;
    EXPECT(addResult(1, 2) == 3);
    std::cout << "Adding 2 and 8..." << std::endl;
    EXPECT(addResult(2, 8) > 1);
    std::cout << "Adding 7 and 4..." << std::endl;
    EXPECT(addResult(7, 4) < 12);
  },
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  return lest::run( specification );
}
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt for my unit test:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/ExecutableTests/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/externalinclude/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Calculator/)
add_executable (unit_test_calculator test_calculator.cpp)
target_link_libraries(unit_test_calculator -Wl,--whole-archive calculator -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

My question is why is the report saying that the library code isn't be covered? Are the data files the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to build your library manually, without CMake? Is coverage OK in that case? You may check which flags are actually used when compile and link your library with `make VERBOSE=1`. Try to build manually with the same flags, and check the coverage.

Comment: Coverage flags should also be present in link stage.

Comment: Off-topic:  You can save typing keystrokes by not using the `this->` notation.  The notation is only required when the member names are the same as the parameter names; you rename the parameters to avoid having to type `this->`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I manually build the library I do get a gcno file. However the report still says there is no coverage for the library. I'm curious as to why the gcno file exists when I do it manually but not with cmake. I would it has to do with a missing flag like Jarod42 is suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue. The problem was that I wasn't running lcov against the source code after running the unit test. I had the wrong directory.

```
lcov -c -d "$1"/bin/test/$component/CMakeFiles/"$unit_test".dir -o "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.run
```

Needed to be:

```
lcov -c -d "$1"/bin/src/$component/CMakeFiles/"$dependency".dir -o "$1/Coverage/$component"_"$dependency".coverage.run
```